# Why is this AsyncCallback test failing some of the time?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, race-condition

I have the following class which tries to act as a simple asynchronous operation :

```
public class AsyncLineWriter
{
    private delegate void SynchronousWriteLineDelegate(string message);
    private SynchronousWriteLineDelegate DoWriteLine;
    private void SynchronousWriteLine(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
    public AsyncLineWriter()
    {
        DoWriteLine = new SynchronousWriteLineDelegate(SynchronousWriteLine);

    public IAsyncResult BeginWriteLine(string message, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        return DoWriteLine.BeginInvoke(message,callback,state);
    }
    public void EndWriteLine(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        DoWriteLine.EndInvoke(asyncResult);
    }
}
```

The following unit test is intermittently failing, but I don't understand where the race condition is:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Callback_is_called()
{
    // Arrange
    AsyncLineWriter lineWriter = new AsyncLineWriter();
    object state = new object();
    object callbackState = null;
    AsyncCallback callback = (r) =>
        {
            callbackState = r.AsyncState;
        };

    // Act
    IAsyncResult asyncResult = lineWriter.BeginWriteLine("test", callback, state);
    lineWriter.EndWriteLine(asyncResult);

    // Assert
    Assert.AreSame(state, callbackState);
}
```

Comment: It seems that the callback is not part of the async operation which EndInvoke is waiting for to end.

Comment: Why is the test passing some of the time, then?

Comment: Because sometimes the two threads interleave in such a way.

Comment: Huh? If you could provide a fix that would make this test pass and still have the desired behavior (proving that the callback was called) then it would be a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this pattern, the callback is run on a thread pool thread and you are supposed to call `EndInvoke` from within the callback.

`EndInvoke` doesn't wait for the callback to complete ( because this would cause a deadlock ), so you have a race between the callback and your test method.

---

EDIT: The wait handle can be set before the callback has completed too. Try this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Callback_is_called()
{
    // Arrange
    var lw = new AsyncLineWriter();

    object state = new object();
    object callbackState = null;

    var mre = new ManualResetEvent( false );

    AsyncCallback callback = r =>
        {
            callbackState = r.AsyncState;

            lw.EndWriteLine( r );

            mre.Set();
        };

    // Act
    var ar = lw.BeginWriteLine( "test", callback, state );
    mre.WaitOne();

    // Assert
    Assert.AreSame( state, callbackState );
}
```

Comment: Interesting that the AsyncWaitHandle can be set before the callback has completed.  This works.

Answer (score 3):

As already noted, on the occasions where the test succeeds you're just being lucky that the threads are interleaving in such a way that the callback gets called before the call to `EndInvoke` occurs. The proper APM pattern is to call your EndWriteLine within the callback which means that you have to pass the `AsyncLineWriter` as part of the state to the `BeginInvoke` method.

EDIT: there's an extra complication since the callback can occur **after** the `IAsyncResult` `WaitHandle` is signalled. So it's not that the callback doesn't get called it's just getting called after the check occurs. This fixes it:

```
AsyncLineWriter lineWriter = new AsyncLineWriter();
Object myState = new Object();
object[] state = new object[2];
state[0] = lineWriter;
state[1] = myState;
object callbackState = null;

ManualResetEvent evnt = new ManualResetEvent(false);

AsyncCallback callback = (r) =>
    {  
        Object[] arr = (Object[])r.AsyncState;
        LineWriter lw = (LineWriter)arr[0];
        Object st = arr[1];
        callbackState = st;
        lw.EndWriteLine(r);
        evnt.Set();
    };

// Act
IAsyncResult asyncResult = lineWriter.BeginWriteLine("test", callback, state);

//asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(); -- callback can still happen after this!

evnt.WaitOne();

//Assert
Assert.AreSame(myState, callbackState);
```

Comment: +1 If `r` is an `AsyncResult`, you could also use `AsyncResult.AsyncDelegate`.

Comment: Okay, looks promising, but this still fails sometimes.  Try it if you don't believe me.

Comment: Okay, I've confirmed. I'll expand the answer to explain.